# Piping input to stdin does not work in c

Tags: c, pipe, stdin, stderr

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int count;
    fprintf(stderr, "Starting program.\n");
    scanf("%d", &count);
    fprintf(stderr, "Read: %d\n", count);

}
```

I am simply trying to read a number from stdin and repeating it on stderr, when i compile and run I see the first stderr print and then the code blocks as expected, but when i pipe input to the program I never see the stderr prints and the program exits immediately.

I tried to add a sleep(5) after the last print to stderr but the program just exits immediately without any output.

```
gcc pipetest.c -o b
echo '2'  > ./b
```

Comment: try `echo 2  | ./b`

Comment: same result, the program finishes and nothing happens.

Comment: try again after remake of b.

Comment: thank you! mind explaining what actually happened here?

Comment: | is pipe (program1 | program2) program1's stdout connect to program2's stdin, > is redirect (program > filename: program's stdout write to file, stdout redirect to file), `echo '2'  > ./b` meant write '2' to file of `b`.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below with

```
echo 2|./b
```

---

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 #include <termios.h>
 int
 main(void)
 {
   int  count;
   struct termios t;
   if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &t) < 0)
   {   
     scanf("%d", &count);
     fprintf(stderr, "Read: %d\n", count);
     return 0;
   }
   fprintf(stderr, "no pipe found \n");
   return -1; 
}
```